# How Do I Publish Shiny a Shiny App to GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, shiny-server, rstudio-server, google-cloud-repository

### What I Have Successfully Accomplished

- I have a shiny app that runs locally.
- I have set up a Ubuntu 19 server on a GCP VM instance
- I have installed RStudio Server & ShinyServer, and [EXTERNAL_IP]:3838 shows the standard geyser app
- I have copy-pasted my code into the RStudio IDE at [EXTERNAL_IP]:8787, and it runs perfectly.

#### *Separately* I have:

- Set up a Cloud Source Repository in the same project
- Successfully connected my local instance of RStudio to the cloud repo.

### What I want to do (if it's not already obvious)

1. I am having trouble figuring out how to connect RStudio/Shiny to the Cloud repo, so that it executes the latest push.
2. How do I assign that IP to my DNS, so that it can be part of my (Google-hosted) website?

Thanks!

Comment: any luck? just wondering

Comment: nope. and i didn't win the client i was going to do that stuff for, so i haven't gotten back to it. but i still need to know -- it'll come up again. any tips?

Comment: not really. I've heard about kubernetes, but this is out of my knowledge level